# How know if ModelState contains errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When a form is posted in my controller, I make the following check:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
```

If the model is not valid, errors are added to the `ModelState`. The model is then passed to the view with validation summary.

However, I want to check if the `ModelState` has errors from inside the jQuery `ready` handler, so that I can add some additional behavior if the form has errors. Is that possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could spit global javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isValid = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid));
</script>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    if (!isValid) {
        alert('opa');
    }
});
```

Comment: in my case `isValid` is always true but i can see the errors my page, what has gone wrong here ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `isValid` is always true in my case too any suggestions you can point out

Comment: @supercool I don't exactly remember that situation but my code is checking each field for errors like this

 `if (ModelState.ContainsKey("ReturnDate")) ModelState["ReturnDate"].Errors.Clear();`

Answer (score 2):

a little addition to @Dimitrov answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isValid = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))';

    if (isValid != 'true')
        // model has some errors...
</script>
```

It's important to use single qoutes around the helper. Otherwise, that ending semicolon `;` cause problems. Nether you can write it, nor you can't, at all cases it cause a syntax error. Unless you put those single quotes around the helper as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Darins Answer:

In .cshtml:

```
@Html.Hidden("IsValid", Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))
```

in JS

```
var isValid = $('#IsValid').val().toLowerCase() == "true";
```