# ModelState.IsValid always true when accessed on View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907630/how-know-if-modelstate-contains-errors) i got the `ModelState.IsValid` ins jquery code. but it is always true, i can see the error on my page. 
What i am trying to achieve is show loading when a form is submitted. I used  `onclick` event of submit. It shows loading even if there are validation errors on page. I don't wanna show loading in this case. I also tried using `Form`'s `Submit` event but same results.

My `ViewModel` is having `DataAnnotations` for validations and form is in a partial view. Any suggestions how can i achieve this loading message successfully ?

This is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmFlightSearch", onsubmit = "CheckModalErros()" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
......
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-3 pull-right">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">
                Search Flights
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It shows loading even if there are validation errors on page. I don't want show loading in this case.

Add this event handler:

```
$("#frmFlightSearch").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
    // hide 'loading' 
});
```

this will trigger when your client-side validation fails and you can hide the whatever it is that you're showing for 'loading' progress.

If client-side validation fails, then it won't post anyway (using asp.net mvc + jquery validation).

Comment: out of curiosity why this is always true ? ` @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))`

Comment: It's not.  It's `true` when the view is first loaded and stays true until your server-side post action returns the updated view - it won't change with client-side validation as there's no server-side code.  If your server-side code doesn't add a manual `ModelState.AddModelError` and is only using the `[Required]` (etc) attributes that are already checked client-side then there will not be any server-side errors (as it won't post to server-side anyway), so it will appear to be true.  Test by adding, at the very top of your post action, `ModelState.AddModelError("", "this is a test");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your form using partial view using an ajax call, in success callback do something like below:

```
$.ajax({
     success: function(data){
                 $('#DivId').html(data);
                 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#FormId"));
             }
});
```

This will parse your form's validation and your form will show validation message when you click on submit and if model is not valid.

Hope this help.

Edit:

As you said on click you need to check below line of code:

```
if($('#FormId).Valid())
{
   $('#Loader').show(); //show loader if form is valid.
}
else
{
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default event if form is not valid.
}
```

Comment: actually the form is submitted by post action not ajax

Comment: Form is getting load while page is loaded?